# Change markers onclick in the spoliers block

Tags: javascript, jquery, marker

I need to create a block of spoilers. A spoilerbody should be displayed onclick, and the spoiler's title should change its icon from "+" to "-" and becom bold. When another spoiler is clicked, the previous one should be hidden and change its icon back from "-" to "+".
In the code below the "+" does changes to "-", but for ALL spoilers and can't be changed any more.
Thanks very much in advance for help!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

//SPOILERS  
var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
    icon.find('span').text('+');
 $('.spoiler_links').click(function()
  {
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('fast');
    var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
    icon.find('span').text('-'); 
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
 display:none;
 }
 .spoiler_links {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#5f6a70;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  font-size:1em;
  }
.spoiler_body {
 font-size:0.9em;
}
.spoilerblock {
 padding:1% 0;
 border-bottom:1px solid #dddede;
}
.icon {
 font-size:1.8em;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#51758c;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="spoilers">
    <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler1 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler2 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler3 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>       
     
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
//SPOILERS  
var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
icon.find('span').text('+');
$('.spoiler_links').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_body').toggle('fast');
    var icon = $(this).find('span.icon');
    icon.text('-');
    return false;
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
var icon = $('.spoiler_links');
          icon.find('span').text('+');

 $('.spoiler_links').click(function()
    {
  $('*').css('font-weight','normal'); 
        var $other_spoilers = $('a.spoiler_links').not(this);
            $other_spoilers.siblings().hide('fast');

           $other_spoilers.find('span').text('+'); 
  $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
        $(this).siblings().toggle('fast', function() {

            var $icon = $(this).siblings('a.spoiler_links').find('span')
            if ($icon.text() == '+') {
                $icon.text('-')
            } else {
                $icon.text('+')
            }

        })

        return false;
    });
   });
```

```css
.spoiler_body {
 display:none;
 }
 .spoiler_links {
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#5f6a70;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  font-size:1em;
  }
.spoiler_body {
 font-size:0.9em;
}
.spoilerblock {
 padding:1% 0;
 border-bottom:1px solid #dddede;
}
.icon {
 font-size:1.8em;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#51758c;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spoilers">
    <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler1 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler2 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>
     <div class="spoilerblock">
        <a href="" class="spoiler_links">Spoiler3 <span class="icon"></span></a>
            <div class="spoiler_body">
                   <p>
                   content
                   </p>
            </div>
     </div>       
     
</div>
```

I found help in another place. If anyone would ever have a question like mine, just use the code above.
Thanks to @user1947472 for time and help!